# Application launches itself on boost::filesystem::exist and CoInitializeSecurity call on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, boost

We have a product in which our windows service launches an agent (`watchDog`) and this agent launches another agent (actual product). This product is tested successfully on windows 7, 8 and 10. But on clients location who has only windows 10 creates a strange problem. When it calls `boost::filesystem::exists` OR `CoInitializeSecurity` the call does not complete, does not throw any exception but it launches itself. The parent ID of first instance is correct, its of `watchDog` agent. But when problem occurs we see two entries of the actual agent, parent ID of first entry is `watchDogAgent` but the parent ID of second entry is process ID of first entry.

This does not happen every time, randomly it happens but at same place. If i comment out the code then agent runs flawlessly. If i comment any one of the problem code, issue occurs exactly at second place.

Please check this image where the output of `wmic` command is shown when issue occurred, issue occurred 8 seconds after the first instance:

[image]

The second instance does not execute anything, not even first line of main. First instance i can kill from taskmanager as it is the only instance listed there. When I kill second instance using 'taskkill' command first time its successful but its entry still persist in wmic output. When i try to kill it again i get 'access denied' error. After 2 to 5 minutes the entry is removed from the wmic output automatically.

Edit 2:
Later we identified that it was heap corruption which was causing the issue. But question still remains, why it was causing the exe to launch again. Here is the output of [processExplorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpDAU.jpg)

Comment: Use a debugger to put a breakpoint into any process creating function. This sounds like a problem in your code.

Comment: Already done that, I'm pretty sure that in above agent "userA*inal.exe" there is no process creation code. Process creation code is in process whose PID is "10008" in above screenshot. For two weeks we are working on resolving this issue. Problem is its not reproducible in our environment, same OS, same configurations, still not.